# how to attach a TextView on a google map Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I might have already asked a similar question but didn't get any answer because I wasn't really precise about what I wanted to do.
So basically I'm using the android-maps-utils (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) from Chris Broadfoot to display short info messages in BubbleIcons on a Google map in my android app.

The thing is I want to attach a TextView to the relative position of a marker on the map to display some other infos which are going to be dynamic (as opposed to the Bitmap pics generated by this great library); a sort of countdown in my case.

Would anyone have any idea of how I could do this programmatically.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library have a class to handle markers icons, its called BubbleIconFactory. By default it change a text inside a marker but you can change it to whatever you want just by setting the content view like this:

```
BubbleIconFactory mBubbleFactory = new BubbleIconFactory(this);
mBubbleFactory.setContentView(mImageView);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(.....);

Bitmap iconBitmap = mBubbleFactory.makeIcon();

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBitmap)).position(MyPosition).title("My current position"));
```

That's hoy you do it with a Image inside the marker but it should be the same with everything you want because you set a view as parameter in the setContentView method. Notice that markers and InfoWindows in maps are not live views but they render like images so there is no way to "refresh" the content without render it again. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb2X9IjjZpM) video will help you with that and I'm not sure but I guess that BubbleIconFactory could be deprecated now and you should use IconGenerator instead, look for it in the library code. Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Also take a look at how plains google maps works to have a better idea of what the library is using:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker?hl=es

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows?hl=es#custom_info_windows

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do use IconGenerator.
I've already seen the video you linked and I was asking myself which part of the code should I put in an AssyncTask to make the icons generation load faster.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Create a custome layout for marker as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_marker_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_center_pin_green_black"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inflate it and add it as a marker icon

```
View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custome_proximity_pin_green, null);
TextView tv_marker_text = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.tv_marker_text);
tv_marker_text.setText("20");


meterMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(meterModel.getLatitude(),meterModel.getLongitude())).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getContext(), marker))));
```

createDrawableFromView method is

```
private Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```